# com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Tags: web-services, soap

I am consuming SOAP service where sending request to soap url and getting the response. But when i try to connect using WebServiceTemplate getting a nested exception as

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
```

Below is the code where i am sending the request to soap client

```
soapClient.sendEmail(request); - From the service to soap client
```

Below is the soap client code to connect and send the request

```
@Service
public class SoapClient {

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;
    
    private WebServiceTemplate template;
    
    @Value("${email.url}")
    String emailUrl;
    
    @Value("${email.vaultQuery}")
    String querytaken;

    @Value("${email.valtQu}")
    String queryp;
    
    public MessageResponse sendEmail(MessageRequest request) {
        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
        String plainCredentials = querytaken + ":" + queryp;
        String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));
        return (MessageResponse) template.marshalSendAndReceive(emailUrl, request,new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
                TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                
                HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();
             
                
                connection.getConnection().setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials); 
            }
            
            
           
    });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out for my issue

Comment: experiencing the same problem, with a spring boot app, have you found a solution for this?